# alguien sabe como conectar estas clases siguiendo los principios de Programacion Orientada a Objetos?

Tags: ruby

Estoy intentando hacer un juego simple de Tic Tac Toe y no logro conectar las classes apropiadamente

````
class Player
  def current_player
    player = 'X'
    player = 'O' if Turn.turn_count.odd?
    player
  end
end

class Board
  attr_accessor :board

  def initialize
    @board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
  end

  WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [6, 4, 2],
    [0, 4, 8]
  ].freeze

  def display_board
    puts " #{@board[0]} | #{@board[1]} | #{@board[2]} "
    puts ' ----------- '
    puts " #{@board[3]} | #{@board[4]} | #{@board[5]} "
    puts ' ----------- '
    puts " #{@board[6]} | #{@board[7]} | #{@board[8]} "
  end
end

class Winner
  def initialize
    @board = Board.new
  end

  def won?
    Board.WIN_COMBINATIONS.detect do |combo|
      @board[combo[0]] == @board[combo[1]] &&
        @board[combo[1]] == @board[combo[2]] &&
        position_taken?(combo[0])
    end
  end

  def full?
    Turn.turn_count == 9
  end

  def draw?
    !won? && full?
  end

  def over?
    won? || full? || draw?
  end

  def winner
    @board[winner.first] if winner == won?
  end
end

class TicTacToe
  def initialize
    @board = Board.new
    @turn = Turn.new
  end

  def play
    until @winner.over?
      Winner.turn()

      if Winner.won?
        winner = Winner.winner()
        puts "Congratulations #{winner}!"
      elsif Winner.draw?
        puts 'Tic Tac Toe Game!'
      end
    end
  end
end

class Turn
  def input_to_index(input)
    input.to_i - 1
  end

  def move(position, token = 'X')
    @board[position] = token
  end

  def position_taken?(input)
    @board[input] == 'X' || @board[input] == 'O'
  end

  def valid_move?(input)
    input.between?(0, 8) && !position_taken?(input)
  end

  def turn
    puts 'Choose a spot between 1-9'
    spot = gets.strip
    spot = input_to_index(spot)
    if valid_move?(spot)
      move(spot, current_player)
    else
      turn
    end
    display_board
  end

  def turn_count
    taken = 0
    @board.each do |i|
      taken += 1 if i.include?('X') || i.include?('O')
    end
    taken
  end
end

game = TicTacToe.new
game.play```
````

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto iba más como comentario, pero tienes muchos problemas en tu código que preferí ponerlo acá como respuesta, aunque no sea la respuesta que quizás esperas.
Empezando porque ni puede ejecutarse el código, apenas se llama a `play` te arroja un `undefined method 'over?'` porque `@winner` no está definido.
Llamas a métodos de instancia como `def turn_count` como si fueran métodos de clase como en

```
player = 'O' if Turn.turn_count.odd?
```

Defines `attr_accessor :board`, para no usarlo nunca en la clase `Board`, ya que de igual forma llamas a `@board`.
En la clase `Turn` llamas a `@board`, pero ni siquiera está definido dentro de la clase. Si quieres interconectar las instancias, debes pasarlas como parámetro en algún momento, ya sea en el constructor (de preferencia) o cuando se llame a un método, pero una instancia de la clase `Turn` no tiene cómo saber de la existencia de los atributos de board, si no se los haces saber explícitamente de alguna forma.
Te sugiero que le des una revisada nuevamente a algún manual o tutorial de POO, porque a pesar de que en primera instancia se ve como que estuviesen bien definidas las entidades u objetos, claramente no se conectan como deberían. Y si, es lo que estás preguntando, pero empezando no hay forma de ver eso sin saber siquiera el planteamiento del ejercicio. Llegar con un código que fue hecho con un pensamiento en mente y preguntar cómo se puede hacer este código POO eventualmente puede ser una tarea en la que simplemente se deseche por completo lo que has hecho, porque cada uno puede tener su manera particular de ver el problema y de como resolverlo.
Te sugeriría que crees una nueva pregunta con un problema puntual que estás teniendo en tu código, la de ahora no es puntual y está abierta a interpretación de cada uno.
Saludos